# Remove sublist from DEEP nestedlist

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm struggling with some NESTED LISTS.
Briefly, inside the list of lists I have some lists containing several value

```
biglist = [[['strings', '632'], ['otherstrings', 'hey']],[['blabla', '924'], ['histring', 'hello']]]
```

from this nested list, I'd like to remove the sublist in which `'hello'` string appears.
I tried this:

```
for sub_line in big_list:
    if 'hello' in sub_line:
        big_list.remove(sub_line)
```

Now, if I print the new `big_list` outside the loop, I get the old list since I didn't assign the updated list to a new list. But if I assign to a new list like:

```
for sub_line in big_list:
    if 'hello' in sub_line:
        updated_list = big_list.remove(sub_line)
print(updated_list)
```

I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'`.

So what's the problem with this?
I CANNOT use list indexing because my real list is huge and the target value is not always in the same place. 
I've already check other questions but nothing is working.
Thank you all!

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: @pault , Actually my list is way more complex. I have sometihing like this: `big_list = [[['string1', 'string2'],['string4','string5']], [['bla','bla'],['bla','bla']]]`. I'd use list comprehension to remove specific list from the inner lists.

Comment: If your input is more complex, then you should specify that in the question. Still, referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/10197418), in `somelist = [x for x in somelist if not determine(x)]`, `determine(x)` could be a function that analyses each element of `somelist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you constantly have two levels of nesting (not what I would label *DEEP*), you could combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/10197418) from the dupe marking by @pault with [list flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/10197418):

```py
biglist = [[['strings', '632'], ['otherstrings', 'hey']],[['blabla', '924'], ['histring', 'hello']]]
token = 'hello'
smalllist = [x for x in biglist if not token in [j for i in x for j in i]]

# smalllist
# Out[17]: [[['strings', '632'], ['otherstrings', 'hey']]]
```

Comment: thank you. I've just started learning/working with python and maybe this nested list is not so deep but the huge amount of data I have inside, makes it looks deep for me. So I succeeded in my aim. I accepted your answer as correct because it provides me further advices. On the other hand, I went through all my script and I correct the nested list from the beginning using only partially your reply. Anyway thanks,I'll better focus on list comprehension!

Comment: @Marco: glad I could help! keep in mind though that this code will only work correctly if you have regular nesting, i.e. that each element of the "main list" is always a list of lists. If not, you will have to include checks and so on - in this case, using an ordinary `for` loop will make for more readable code compared to putting it all in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me. You need to remove sub_line (not line) form the list.

```
big_list = [['strings', '632', 'otherstrings', 'hey'],['blabla', '924', 'histring', 'hello']]

print(big_list)
for sub_line in big_list:
    if 'hello' in sub_line:
        big_list.remove(sub_line)
print(big_list)
```

Comment: Mhh, probably I copied wrongly my code. The "line" should be "sub_line", yes. :) Edited

Answer (score 0):

```
for sublist in biglist:
      if 'hello' in sublist:
            updated_list=biglist.remove(sublist)
print(updated_list)
```

The output of the above code is `None` because `remove()` does not return any value i.e, it returns `None`. So you should not assign return value of `remove()` in a list.
I think that might cause some problems whenever you will use `updated_list`.

Comment: Thank you and what do you suggest to use?

Comment: Since remove() modifies the list in place so, use biglist instead of updated_list.